# How to fix approval system in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, comments

I made a blog and I can leave comments to my articles, then I made an Approve button, need to make the approve function.

I need to make it to work. I just can't, no matter what I try. I want to be able to approve or not a comment before it's posted. I have tried everything I could think of.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class CommentsController extends AppController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $comments = $this->Comments->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('comments'));
    }

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $comment = $this->Comments->get($id);
        $this->set(compact('comment'));
    }

    public function add()
    {
    $comment = $this->Comments->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $comment = $this->Comments->patchEntity($comment, $this->request->data);
        $comment->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $comment->aproved = 0;
        $comment->article_id = $this->request->data['article_id'];
        if ($this->Comments->save($comment)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your comment has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view', $comment->article_id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your comment.'));
    }
    $this->set('comment', $comment);
    }

    public function aprove()
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: That's the point. I'm stuck. Don't know how make it work. I have tried 100 diffrent ways

Comment: It' s set on null. And it dosen't change when i add a comment

Comment: okey, it's done. thanks a lot

Comment: @KurtaFlorentina I highly suggest reading through the book, about what the MVC layers how, and what Cake's request cycle looks like. That would clear up a lot of your questions. Questions like these aren't really appropriate for SO as it's not a specific programming question.

Comment: @KurtaFlorentina  please mark and up-vote the answer for others help.

Comment: people are not interested in marking the answer even after there problem is resolved and they said: -`it works. thanks a lot `. Really frustrating. Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Your link should look like this:

```
$this->Html->link('approve', array('controller' => 'your-controller', 'action' => 'aprove', $comment_id, $value['Comment']['aproved']));
```

and your controller function is:

```
public function aprove($comment_id, $approve_value)
{
  if(isset($comment_id) && !empty($comment_id)){
       $approve = $this->Comments->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$comment_id),'fields'=>array('Comment.id, Comment.approve')));
       if(!empty($approve)){
           $this->Comments->id = $approve['Comment']['id'];
           $this->Comments->saveField('aproved', $approve_value);
       }
  }
}
```